# How to append a Word after a certain word in java

Tags: java

I have got this key value pairs under my properties file

```
mailsubject = REDEX Application --- Credentials
mailtext = Dear User,\n \
          Following Are the credentials for REDEX Mapping Application  -- pwd
setFrom = xxxs31@gmail.com
```

This is where i am using them in my java file for sending email through java

```
try {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setSubject(props_load.getProperty("mailsubject"));
        message.setText(props_load.getProperty("mailtext") + "  " +generatedpwd);
        Transport.send(message);
        result = "success";
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        result = "fail";
        logger.error("Exception Occured"+ "sendemalto" +sendemalto , e);
    }
```

My question is ,

Is it possible to insert User name after the word , so that it looks like

**Dear User Kiran ,
          Following Are the credentials for REDEX Mapping Application**

Comment: If you have frequent requirements like this, you may want to have a look at templating engines.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793880/lightweight-template-engine-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about defining a placeholder and replacing it with your username:

```
props_load.getProperty("mailtext").replace("{{username}}", username)
```

With your template being like this:

```
mailtext = Dear User {{username}},\n ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    MessageFormat form = new MessageFormat("Dear {0}, following...");

    String userName = "Kiran";
    Object[] testArgs = {userName};

    System.out.println( form.format(testArgs) );
```

Output: "Dear Kiran, following..."

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

Use either String.replace(), String.replaceFirst() or String.replaceAll(), depending on what you want to do.

String.replace() replaces a given text with another one. So you can just do this:

```
"Dear User, Following are...".replace("User","User "+username);
```

Or if you need more control use String.replaceFirst() or String.replaceAll() together with a regex. replaceFirst() only replaces the first occurrence, whereas replaceAll() replaces all occurrences:

```
"Dear User, Following are...".replaceFirst("^Dear User"), "Dear User "+username);
```

Regex gives you much more control but is quite a bit more complex, so you'd need to read up on it to use it properly.